# Clarification of a quote on Riemann-Roch Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, ideals, math-history

I find this quote in Martin Krieger, Doing Mathematics: Convention, Subject, Calculation, Analogy, New Jersey, World Scientific Publishing, 2003, p. 223.

"Hilbert then shows how one of Dedekind's notions of a prime factor or ideal (the different) corresponds to the Riemann-Roch theorem, a geometric and arithmetic fact concerning the topology of Riemann's surfaces."

Could anyone explain it to me in some not too tecnical detail? What does "the different" mean in that context?

Comment: Have you looked it up in Wikipedia or a book? Difficult to answer when you say 'not too technical detail', very subjective.

Comment: @Mohan I mean, a clarification of what the paragraph says and of the criterion allowing dor that special kind of ideals as compared with all others.

Comment: I think the different is referring to the [different ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_ideal), but I'm not sure.  [More info here.](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/different.pdf)

Comment: @SpamIAm. Yes, it is referring to that. But the point is, I do not quite understand it.